# Understanding a circuit with a capacitor

Tags: electric-circuits

I'm trying to understand what a capacitor does in a circuit.  Suppose we have a super basic circuit:

[image: Circuit with a 9 volt battery and a 1 microfarad capacitor]

Does the capacitor open the circuit and cause current to stop flowing?

Comment: after a  time dependent on resistance and capacitance of the circuit, yes. (in this case very short as there is minimal resistance). That's the time it takes to charge up its plates to 9V.

Comment: -1. No research effort. This is a very basic question. The answer is easily found in textbooks and on the internet. eg Try googling your question.

Answer (score 3):

The battery will pull some electrons off of the top plate causing it to become positively charged. As that happens, electrons will be attracted to the bottom plate by the top plate, but the electrons can't flow across the gap of the capacitor, so they collect. This process continues until the voltage across the capacitor plates equals the voltage across the battery, and charges will stop moving.  The speed at which this happens depends on the resistance in the battery and wires, along with the capacitance.

When it stops, the positive charge magnitude on the top plate will equal the negative charge magnitude on the bottom, and the total charge on the capacitor will be zero, BUT, there is a charge separation (+Q and -Q) so there is energy stored in the system.

Comment: I would also add that while the electrons fill one of the plates and leave the other that motion is a *current* on the wires that will generate a magnetic field surrounding the circuit. Now after the cap reaches the battery voltage you change the polarity of the battery then a reverse motion will take place and you if keep doing this you get an oscillation with some radiation, too.